# jQuery datepicker onSelect set multiple row values

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

On the select event of the datepicker I need to add and set values in multiple rows. In other words, I have something like this...

```
     Days     Value
```

Row 1    7

Row 2    2

Row 3    3

I have the "Days" and "Value" columns as textboxes. When I select a date from the datepicker I need to add the "Days" value for each row to the date selected. That value is what goes into the "Value" column. Example, I select 4/20/2010. The value in each respective row would then be 4/28/2010, 4/22/2010, 4/23/2010.

Hopefully this makes sense and thank you for the help in advance.

EDIT -------

Luis, I've tried implementing your code with what I had and have a question. I selected from my datepicker 4/21/2010. So the first row, in my example above, should be 4/28/2010. I'm not getting that though. It's returning 11/3/2010. Can you or someone help me please with understanding why. Thanks.

Thank you for the update. It was helpful.

Comment: I just edit my answer, check the new one I have tested it and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you have an input filed with an id of datePicker adn the table has an id of myTable:

```
  $("#myTable tr").each(
        function() {
            var calcDate = new Date($("#datePicker").val());
            calcDate.setDate(calcDate.getDate() + parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()));
            var formatDate = (calcDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + calcDate.getDate() + "/" + calcDate.getFullYear()

            $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(formatDate);
        }

 );
```